# Disable the shortcuts feature in Yahoo! Mail

Tags: yahoo-mail

I've noticed that Yahoo's shortcut feature has come back (presumably because a cookie or account setting got flipped). I tried finding the setting to disable it but alas, no luck.

I have already reviewed the instructions [here](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/yahoomail/tools/tools-84.html), but unfortunately the option doesn't appear to be available.

I'm referring to the feature where certain words in the email body are highlighted and you can click on the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've found a solution - Yahoo! changed the `turn off` option from search box (question mark). You must go to the bottom of left menu (folders, etc.) and click `settings` icon of `Applications` and then find the Shortcut app and remove it.

More information [here](http://help.yahoo.com/l/in/yahoo/mail/ymail/basics/mltamshrtct2.html)

Comment: Thanks Perl, it worked for me.  @Alex - might need to logout/login again?

Answer (score 0):

You can't turn it off anymore.

> **Note:** The keyboard shortcuts cannot be turned off.

From [this help page](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/yahoomail/basics/basics-65.html). (Scroll to the bottom of the page.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback but I'm not referring to keyboard shortcuts.  I'm referring to the feature where certain words in the email body are highlighted and you can click on the link.